# I am stuck in this binary search problem in geeks for geeks (time limit exceeded)

Tags: c++

**C++** I don't know what went wrong or am I missing something ? always getting a time limit exceeded.

```
class Solution {
  public:
    int binarysearch(int arr[],int n,int k){

        int low  = 0;
        int high = n-1;
        while(low < high){
            int mid = (low + high)/2;
            if(arr[mid] == k){
                return mid;
            }
            else if(arr[mid] < k){
                high = mid + 1;
            }
            else{
                low = mid-1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried running your own code in a debugger and testing it yourself to see how it behaves?

Comment: I have come across this site (geeks for geeks) many times. They have almost every program contains errors or glitches

Comment: `int arr[]` should be `std::span`, `std:array` or `std::vector`. `int` is too small for an index. `int mid = (low + high)/2;` causes UB, use `std::midpoint`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a hint.

Take a closer look at this:

```
        else if(arr[mid] < k){
            high = mid + 1;
        }
        else{
            low = mid-1;
        }
```

Now ask yourself.  If `arr[mid]` is **less than** the value to be searched for, what range of indices should be searched for on the next iteration? Then compare that to what the code is actually doing.